# Get top k searched objects fails (REST API mongoose)

Tags: node.js, rest, limit, mongoose-schema

I set up my mongoose model, and want to get the top k searched objects based on one of the field, "numberOfSearched". when I passed a number into the limit function, it works perfectly. But I want it to be dynamic that it returns a number of objects based on the value indicated in the endpoint parameters, but it keeps return all of them when I replace the number with "req.params.number". Any spot check would be appreciated!! Thanks ahead

object,.route.js

```js
// Getting top k
router.get("/top-k/:number", async (req, res) => {
  Word.find({})
    .sort({ numberOfSearched: -1 })
    .limit(req.params.number)
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(docs);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just have to add + plus before req.params.number whatever you pass into url it will be consider as string use
+req.params.number or parseInt(req.params.number)